# Is there a way to fetch data from Firebase that was recently uploaded?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there a way to fetch Data from Firebase that was recently uploaded or in an order that we want (not according to the alphabetical order).

Comment: hello there, its a nice question, can you write in the question what programming language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

yes there is, assuming you are using firebase and javascript, you can listen to changes made in specific branch or the whole database.

proper explanation by firebase team is given [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#web_value_events). Basically it is the `on('value', (snapshot)=>{}` function which will listen to changes on the reference you assign it to. I would advise that you use firestore as its more suited for listening and filtering information, which is what you are looking for.